# why does my if elif loop fail to consistently find string in data

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code is reading urls from a csv file, doing a GET on their content, parsing the response, and writing output to a second csv. If a keyword is found, I need it to output certain data; if not found, it should output a subset of that data. In other words, not all columns of the csv file would be populated in all cases.

My 4 row test file is constructed so that the keyword is missing in the first iteration, present in the second, missing in third, present in last.The code below will find the keyword and populate the csv correctly the first time it iterates through, but it doesn't find it in the last instance. I can't figure out what is wrong with my if/elif loop:

```
        counter = 0
        for row in list_reader:

            key_id = row['keyId']
            ex_id = row['key']
            get_response = key.get_item(row['keyId'])
            #get_item is a method from the imported Client
            length = (get_response['length'])
            word = (get_response['transcript']['words'][0]['w'])
            if word != "[keyword1]" and word != "[keyword2]":
                print "other",counter
                results_writer.writerow([key_id,ex_id,length])

            elif word == "[keyword1]":
                print word, counter
                x = (get_response['value1'])
                y = (get_response['value2'])
                counter = counter + 1                
                results_writer.writerow([key_id,ex_id,length,x,y])
```

With this the output from the terminal is:

```
    other 0
    [PCI] 0
    other 1
    other 1
```

If it were working properly, the last "other" would be another "[PCI]". It  populates the csv file accordingly the first time, but after that it populates as if the keyword never appears again.

How can I fix the loop so it iterates successfully to find the keyword after the first time?

Comment: Can you give a sample content of your csv file please?

Comment: Your `for` loop it not doing anything but running the exact same part of code multiple times. You don't use the loop variable (`item`) anywhere in your code.

Comment: Are you sure it is indented correctly? The `elif` is broken from the `if` statement by `results_writer.writerow([key_id,ex_id,length,x,y])`.

Comment: @Haramoz do you mean what it's reading or the output?

Comment: @GeeTransit Where would the elif go instead? If I put it underneath the results_writer line I get the error "invalid syntax". I was wondering about that breaking up of the statement as well but I haven't been able to find how to adjust it so I don't get an error

Comment: Indent the `results_writer.writerow([key_id,ex_id,length,x,y])` in your question. It breaks up the code and causes `SyntaxError`. Adding four spaces before the line should work.

Comment: I meant the inputs, I would print the word variable, it may be containing extra spaces which needs to be trimmed, and add an else statement for debugging too. It will help, if you print the variable inside else statement. also print x,y,a,b for debug purpose. you will find the issue there surely. :)

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I found the problem. It happened that [PCI] was the first word in the 2nd instance. My word variable only would find the first word. So in the other instance, since it wasn't the first word, it didn't trigger.